# Removing File type association from Windows 8

Tags: file-association, context-menu, modern-ui

I have created a metro style app similar to Windows Photo Viewer using C#. The app is also displayed in the OpenWith context menu of image files. But, due to some reasons the app is not working. So, I need to remove that app from the FileType associations of the OpenWith context menu. 
Can anyone help me out for doing that? Also, I would like to know how to update the Local App Package of a metro style app to show the effect of the latest build.